# Access vba go to next tab in tabbed userform

Tags: vba

I created a userform with navigation from access toolbar.

I need to define a button that moves to the next tab in the navigation.

The element that handles tabs is named navigationcontrol.

I read the referance page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff851947(v=office.14).aspx) few times. I was not able to find a method or property to change the current tab. I example I found on the internet were not working on the new access.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a couple of information: 1) name of tab control (not name of tab) and 2) value of tab you want selected (fyi - each tab is designated a page index number starting from 0).

Behind your button click event, simply type.

Relative reference:

```
Me.tabctrlname = integervalueoftab
```

Absolute reference:

```
Forms!yourfrmname!tabctrlname = integervalueoftab
```